# Synthesis of Anthracene: Mechanism

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, hydrocarbons

Recently, I happened to find a problem that involved the synthesis of anthracene from bromobenzene in the presence of tert-butyl lithium, using THF as the solvent, and at room temperature.  I am wondering the mechanism for this transformation.

Taking into account that THF degrades in tert-butyl lithium this is the one that I thought of,

It starts with aryne formation.  Benzyne reacts with ethene in a [2+2] cycloaddition.  This undergoes cycloreversion.  The resulting product reacts with another mole of benzyne to create the dihydro-derivative.  This reacts with another equivalent of tert-butyl lithium to form anthracene.

I have a question regarding this.  I do not think a cycloreversion could occur at room temperature (wiki gives a temperature of 180 degrees and states that the conrotary opening is unfavored).  Is this the case or not?  Am I missing another possible mechanism here?

[image: Drawing of structure]

Comment: Bromobenzene is fairly stable towards lithium halogen exchange, without generation of a benyzyne.

Comment: @AS_1000 It might represent some work (e.g., barrelene), however a small graphic illustration of your suggested mechanism would ease to follow your argumentation.  As a word of caution, BuLi is known to react with etheral solvents (hence tBuLi is sold in alkanes, and never in THF) to a degree that in conjunction with TMEDA you may use it synthetically (in case of THF, yielding ethene and the Li enolate of acetaldehyde).

Comment: Thanks for that, I proposed another mechanism using THF, I also added drawings, but I still have a question regarding it because it involves a cycloreversion that I don't think would be possible at room temperature.

Answer (score 2):

I found a research paper<sup>[[1]](https://doi.org/10.1039/P19750000964)</sup> which specifically talks about the reaction you mention. The paper also mentions the same mechanism as you do:

> TETRAHYDROFURAN (THF) (1) is known <sup>1</sup> to react with strong bases like
> butyl-lithium, and the product (2) is known to decompose by a
> retro-cycloaddition to give ethylene (3), and the enolate ion (4) of
> acetaldehyde.
> [image: retro-cycloaddition]
> Enolate ions (6) are
> known <sup>2</sup> to react with benzyne (5) to give dihydrobenzocyclobutenes (7),
> and the dihydrobenzocyclobutenes are known to decompose by an
> electrocyclic opening to give o-xylylenes (9), which are
> [image: electrocyclic opening to give o-xylylenes]
> trapped by the
> benzyne to give dihydroanthracenols (11). By putting these known
> reactions together we have found a very simple ' one-pot ' synthesis
> of symmetrical 9,lO-unsubstituted anthracenes.

The paper uses warm THF to conduct the reaction which shows that cycloreversion of the side ring actually takes place even at a temperature lower than 180°C.

> When bromobenzene (13) is added to a solution of a four-fold excess of
> N-lithio-2,2,6,6-tetramethylpiperidine (15) in **warm** THF, the major
> neutral product is anthracene (16) (63% based on bromobenzene).
> [image: bromobenzene to anthracene]

The paper also talks about what happens when the reaction temperature is changed:

> *Variations in the Reaction Conditions.*-The reaction was carried out as described above, but with the following modifications. (i) When the
> butyl-lithium and the tetramethylpiperidine were mixed slowly at 0°
> and the reaction carried out at 20°, there was no anthracene formed,
> and Nphenyl-2,2,6,6-tetramethylpiperidine was the major product (75%
> by n.m.r.). (ii) When the butyl-lithium and the tetramethylpiperidine
> were mixed at reflux temperature and then cooled to 0° before adding
> the bromobenzene, anthracene was formed (40%, pure). We were not able
> to isolate dihydrobenzocyclobutanol. ... (iv) When butyllithium (5
> mmol) and tetramethylpiperidine (6 mmol) were mixed at -78° and then
> the mixture was brought to reflux temperature before adding the
> bromobenzene (1 mmol), the yield of anthracene was the same as in the
> original reaction.

---

**Reference:**

<sup>([1](https://doi.org/10.1039/P19750000964))   Fleming, I.; Mah, T. A Simple Synthesis of Anthracenes. *J. Chem. Soc., Perkin Trans. 1* **1975**, No. 10, 964.</sup>