# What's this reaction converting 9,10-dihydroanthracene into anthracene

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, organic-oxidation

I have no idea what this reaction converting 9,10-dihydroanthracene into anthracene is. Could someone help me with the name of the reaction/ or explain the mechanism of the formation of the product? 9,10-Dihydroanthracene has been **heated in the presence of sulphur (S)** to give anthracene. How?

[image]

Comment: It's likely a radical mechanism.

Comment: The rxn. is a2-electron oxidation of the substrate. What happens to sulfur?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/77342/synthesis-of-anthracene-mechanism

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/61545/birch-reduction-of-anthracene https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/173843/oxidation-mechanism-of-a-peroxide-reacting-with-a-sulfide-to-form-anthracene